# Response from fetch into table row

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views

This is a bit of two questions in one. I am trying to render the response after a fetch into a table row/data.

```
    UsersRow = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: _.template("-"),
        tagName: 'td',

        initialize: function() {


            this.users = new Collections.AllUsers();
            this.users.fetch({
                success: function(response) {

                    this.response = response;

                    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.response));

                    return this.response;


                }


            }); 

// these two are undefined
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.response));
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users.response));



 },

        render: function(options) {



            return this;
        }


    });
```

The first console.log works perfectly, fetching everything as it should. The second one, not at all. What is wrong?

Also, how to I render it to each of table rows?

Thank you.

Comment: Regarding your second question of rendering to table rows, what do you have so far? You might try looking into [Marionette's collection view](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.collectionview.md) — I've used it for rendering collections to tables a few times.

Comment: let me know if you get some problem with my code.

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin getting an Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement (anonymous function) when doing a return UsersRow;

Comment: try take a look at this sample code. https://github.com/datomnurdin/service-finder-mobile

Answer (score 1):

In answer to your first question, your logging immediately after calling fetch, not within the success callback.

Fetching is asynchronous, you're not guaranteed to have the results back when you try logging. I have annotated your `initialize` function to show the order in which your code is executed. All code relying on `this.response` will need to execute after `success` has been called.

```
initialize: function() {

  // 1
  this.users = new Collections.AllUsers();

  // 2
  this.users.fetch({

    // 4
    // Success will be called after the async request completes
    success: function(response) {
      this.response = response;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.response));
      return this.response;
    }
  }); 

  // 3
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.response));
  console.log(JSON.stringify(this.users.response));

}
```

Comment: So how do I call this.response in the render function, after the async as been done?

Comment: Yeah. If you need to use `this.response` in render then you probably want to call `this.render();` after you set `this.response = response`;

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
var UserModel = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var UserCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: UserModel,
    url: "http://example.com/get_all_users.php",
    parse: function(data) {
        return data;
    }
});
var UsersRow = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#page"),
    render: function() {
        var that = this;
        this.collection = new UserCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({
            type: "GET",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(collection, response) {
                var template = _.template(userTemplate, {
                    users: that.collection.models
                });
                that.$el.html(template);
            },
            error: function(collection, response) {
                alert("error");
            }
        });
    }
});
return UsersRow;
```

You web service can be able request and response JSON data.

You can visit these site for your reference.

http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/02/25/crud-operation-using-jquery-mobile-on-android-part-2/

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/